# Multi Column Deep Neural Network with TFLearn and Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

I am trying to build a multi column deep neural network (MDNN) with tflearn and tensorflow. The MDNN is explained in [this paper](http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/nn2012traffic.pdf). The part I am struggling with is how I can add two or more inputs together to be fed to tensorflow.

For a single column I have:

```
network = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, image_shape, image_shape, 3])
```

and

```
model.fit(X_input, y_train, n_epoch=50, shuffle=True,
      validation_set=(X_test_norm, y_test),
      show_metric=True, batch_size=240, run_id='traffic_cnn2')
```

where `X_input` is of shape `(31367, 32, 32, 3)`. I am pretty new to numpy, tensorflow and tflearn. The difficulty for now really lays in how to specify multiple inputs to tflearn.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MDNN explained in the paper individually trains several models using random (but bounded) distortions on the data. Once all models are trained, they produce predictions using an ensemble classifier by averaging the output of all the models on different versions of the data.

As far as I understand, the columns are not jointly but independently trained.  So you must create different models and call fit on each on them. I recommend you start training a single model and once you have a training setting getting good results, replicate it. To generate predictions, you must compute the average of the predicted probabilities from the *predict* function and take the most probable class.

One way to a generate data from your inputs is to use [data augmentation](http://tflearn.org/data_augmentation/#data-augmentation). However, instead of generating new data you must replace it by the modified versions.